# When the distribution is negatively skewed, how do you find the probability that a sample would be less than ___?

Tags: statistics

I think my question has a really simple answer, but I’d still really appreciate your help :)

I’m given that a distribution is negatively skewed with a mean of 55 and a variance of 15, and then am asked: for a random sample of n=80, what is the probability that X is less than 54 and X is between 54 and 58.

I know how to go about this if it was normally distributed which would be to find the expected value of m and then the z-score. I’m wondering if that would be the same for a distribution that is negatively skewed.

Thank you!

Comment: There are an infinite number of negatively skewed distributions sharing the same mean and variance, and thus it is logically impossible to give an answer without knowing the *precise* distribution at hand.

Comment: What's the context here - are you sure it's not a question about the probabilities of $\mu_x$, and the information you're given isn't sample mean and sample variance? Because then you can apply the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), which would allow you to do what you're thinking of with a normal distribution and a Z-score.